# Spring-Boot + Camel + producerTemplate = thousands of threads

Tags: spring, ssh, memory-leaks, spring-boot, apache-camel

---UPDATE---
As it turns out the heap is getting emptied after some time. However the number of threads just grows without end. On my mac with 8Gb of RAM I am fine, but on a production machine with 1Gb I am getting:

> Exception in thread "Thread-341" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: unable to create new native thread

---

I did write a simple app using Spring Boot (1.2.7.RELEASE) and Apache Camel (2.15.0). The app is simple and has only 1 route: a timer will invoke a method on a bean every 1s. The method invoked will use `ProducerTemplate` to ssh into a remote machine, execute a small script, and print out the output to the console. Simple, right?
However, when profiling this, I can see the number of threads, and heap go through the roof! It seems like any threads created for the ssh are never killed, but parked instead. Because of that I run OOM pretty quickly.
Let me show you some profiler output:
[image: heap/threads monitor]
[image: threads list]
[image: heap cleaned]

As you can see the threads/heap go up and up very quickly.
The app code is minimal, so I will provide it all here for reference.
**pom.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>tests</groupId>
    <artifactId>camel-producer-template-testing</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <start-class>app.Application</start-class>
        <camel.version>2.15.0</camel.version>
        <spring-boot.version>1.2.7.RELEASE</spring-boot.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-core</artifactId>
            <version>${camel.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-spring</artifactId>
            <version>${camel.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-spring-boot</artifactId>
            <version>${camel.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-ftp</artifactId>
            <version>${camel.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-ssh</artifactId>
            <version>${camel.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <!-- Import dependency management from Spring Boot -->
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-boot.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <finalName>${project.artifactId}-${project.version}</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-boot.version}</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>repackage</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

**Application.java:**

```
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

import java.util.TimeZone;

@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@ComponentScan
public class Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        TimeZone.setDefault(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
        SpringApplication application = new SpringApplication(Application.class);
        application.run(args);
    }
}
```

**MyAppContext.java:**

```
import org.apache.camel.CamelContext;
import org.apache.camel.RoutesBuilder;
import org.apache.camel.builder.RouteBuilder;
import org.apache.camel.spring.SpringCamelContext;
import org.apache.sshd.common.keyprovider.FileKeyPairProvider;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.PropertySource;

@Configuration
@PropertySource("application.properties")
public class MyAppContext {

    private final String sshKeyPath = "/Users/gruszd/.ssh/id_rsa";

    @Autowired
    private ApplicationContext applicationContext;

    @Bean
    public CamelContext camelContext() {
        return new SpringCamelContext(applicationContext);
    }

    @Bean
    FileKeyPairProvider keyPairProvider() {
        return new FileKeyPairProvider(new String[]{sshKeyPath});
    }

    @Bean
    RoutesBuilder myRouter() {
        return new RouteBuilder() {
            @Override
            public void configure() throws Exception {
                from("timer://foo?period=1000").to("bean:sftpStager?method=stage");
            }
        };
    }
}
```

**SftpStager.java:**

```
import org.apache.camel.ProducerTemplate;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class SftpStager {

    @Autowired
    private ProducerTemplate producerTemplate;

    public void stage() throws Exception {
        String response = producerTemplate.requestBody(
                "ssh://_remote.machine.url.here_?username=_username_&keyPairProvider=#keyPairProvider",
                "/home/_username_/some_temp_script.sh",
                String.class);
        System.out.println("----");
        System.out.println(response);
        System.out.println("----");
    }
}
```

As you can see the app is very minimal, and it works (I can see the output of the remote script in my console where the app is running). But like I said, it eats up memory like fresh cookies!
Now I did read [this](http://camel.apache.org/why-does-camel-use-too-many-threads-with-producertemplate.html) . However, in my app the `ProducerTemplate` is a bean instantiated by the `Camelcontext` itself. Therefore I can't `producerTemplate.stop()` because the next trigger would throw an exception saying the template is not started...
So my main question is: am I using the `ProducerTemplate` in a wrong way? And if I do, how should I use it?
If I am not doing anything wrong, is that a bug? Should I report it?

Comment: Could you please try to perform the very same test using last released version of Camel 2.15.4? Just to keep dealing with the same minor.

Comment: Exactly the same situation with the latest Camel. After running this for 3min I had almost 2000 threads sitting there...

Comment: Stupid question: Why do you use a ProducerTemplate at all? Just do 'code'  from("timer://foo?period=1000").setBody(simple("/home/_username_/some_temp_script.sh")).to("ssh://_remote.machine.url.here_?username=_username_&keyPairProvider=#keyPairProvider").log(...)

Comment: The example I presented is very simplified scenario. In reality I am generating the url, the username is dynamically chosen based on some other things etc. Also, depending on spring profile I might load different implementations of the bean etc.

Answer (score 0):

As noted by the original poster:

> Turns out it is a bug in Apache Camel itself, should be [and was] fixed in 2.16.2: [Jira Issue here](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CAMEL-9319)

Answer (score 0):

You must stop / clear the state of the producerTemplate.

There are in-built methods like `producerTemplate.stop()` or in your case, since you had autowired the Producer template, you could try `producerTemplate.cleanUp()`